# Проблема с пониманием работы cin

Tags: c++, потоки-данных, cin

Я новичок в программировании, изучаю его по книге Страуструпа. В главе 6 описан код и часть этого кода вызывает затруднение в понимании, а именно следующий блок:

```
Token Token_stream::get()
{
    if (full) { // do we already have a Token ready?
        full = false; // remove Token from buffer
        return buffer;
    }
    char ch;
    std::cin >> ch; // note that >> skips whitespace (space, newline, tab, etc.)
    switch (ch) {
    case ';': // for “print”
    case 'q': // for “quit”
    case '(': case ')': case '+': case '-': case '*': case '/':
        return Token{ ch }; // let each character represent itself
    case '.':
    case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
    case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
    { std::cin.putback(ch); // put digit back into the input stream
        double val;
        std::cin >> val; // read a floating-point number
        return Token{ '8',val }; // let ‘8’ represent “a number”
    }
    default:
        error("Bad token");
    }
}
```

В нем мне не понятна работа `cin`, каким образом он считывает данные из потока?

Если непонятна суть моего вопроса, то задавайте свои уточняющие вопросы. Это мой первый опыт использования stackoverflow

Comment: `каким образом он считывает данные из потока?` Что именно не понятно? Как электроны по проводам бегают?

Comment: как происходит считывание в переменные ch и val. и принцип работы входного потока, как в нем хранятся введенные значения

Comment: В смысле на низком уровне как это происходит? Ну, это надо исходники компилятора смотреть, как там разбирается входной поток.

Comment: как мы используем std::cin для записи значений в переменные, не прибегая к вводу с клавиатуры. к примеру мы ввели число 2, далее оно обрабатывается данной функцией, в которой неоднократно используется std::cin, но снова вводить значения с клавиатуры не требуется

Comment: А, вы про это. Обратите внимание на код `std::cin.putback(ch);`, к нему и комментарий есть, что он делает. Достаточно на начальном уровне знать английский, чтобы понять, что эта функция делает судя по её названию ("положи обратно" буквально) и что в комментарии написано.

Comment: спасибо, как я понял просто значение переменной `ch` возвращается обратно в `cin`. но как присваивается значение переменной `ch`?

Comment: Почитайте ниже мой ответ, я прямо по строчкам уже разобрал.

Comment: да, большое спасибо, на тот момент еще не заметил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрал фрагменты кода, работающие с `stdin`.

Читаем один символ (потому что переменная типа "символ"):

```
    char ch;
    std::cin >> ch; // note that >> skips whitespace (space, newline, tab, etc.)
```

Смотрим, что за символ мы прочитали, разбираем случай, если прочитали цифру:

```
    switch (ch) {
    // ...
    case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
    case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
```

В этом случае буквально "кладём обратно" (`putback`) полученный символ из `ch` обратно в `stdin`:

```
    { std::cin.putback(ch); // put digit back into the input stream
```

Дальше уже заново читаем из `stdin` число с плавающей точкой:

```
        double val;
        std::cin >> val; // read a floating-point number
```